# Out of bounds searching 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to search through an array of arrays (17 rows and 26 columns) for one integer and print the index of that integer. For the sake of easy testing I've set the integer I'm searching for to 0, and all the array values are left default (0), so I should see every index printed by the time my code is finished running.

The rows are printing correctly, but an out of bounds exception is thrown when columnIncrement > 16.

Anybody know what I did wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
private static void search(int[][] arrayofArrays, int num) {

    for(int rowIncrement = 0; rowIncrement < arrayofArrays.length; rowIncrement++) {
        for (int columnIncrement = 0; columnIncrement < arrayofArrays[columnIncrement].length; columnIncrement++) {
            if (arrayofArrays[rowIncrement][columnIncrement] == num) {
                System.out.println("The integer you are looking for is in " + rowIncrement + "-" + columnIncrement);
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] data = new int[17][26];
    int integer = 0;

    search(data, integer); 
}
```

Comment: can you post the stack trace too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your for loop should be

```
 for(int rowIncrement = 0; rowIncrement < arrayofArrays.length; rowIncrement++) {
    for (int columnIncrement = 0; columnIncrement < arrayofArrays[rowIncrement].length; columnIncrement++) {
        if (arrayofArrays[rowIncrement][columnIncrement] == num) {
            System.out.println("The integer you are looking for is in " + rowIncrement + "-" + columnIncrement);
        }
    }
}
```

In second for loop you are checking as arrayOfArrays[columnIncrement] instead of arrayOfArrays[rowIncrement] thats what causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

change `arrayofArrays[columnIncrement].length` to `arrayofArrays[rowIncrement].length` in your second `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your second for loop needs to have `arrayofArrays[rowIncrement].length`.

Answer (score 1):

In your inner loop, you should have: `columnIncrement < arrayofArrays[rowIncrement].length`